# PHP sum checkbox values on ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I would like to sum checked checkbox values via ajax request.

```
<form1>
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box[]' value='value01'>
</form1>
<form2>
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box[]' value='value02'>
</form2>
<form3>
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box[]' value='value03'>
</form3>
```

I'm using ajax form serialize:

```
 data: $(this.form).serialize(),
            url: 'file.php',
            dataType: 'json',
             ....
```

and php file content is:

```
$sum=0;
foreach($_POST['check_box'] as $shipping) {
    $shipping = $shipping;
    $sum +=  $shipping;

  }
  echo json_encode($sum);
```

but ajax return a error? Could it be because is multiple forms?

Comment: why are you using multiple forms?

Comment: why you checking the sum of checkbox checkboxed values by ajax. You could had done with jquery itself ri*?

Comment: i'm generating forms with php script (each form has submit button)

Comment: @Plum because this just example.

Comment: Are the values in your check boxes strings? Because it's hard to "add up" with strings like that, and why are you assigning `$shipping` to itself only to put it into `$sum` ?

Comment: SOLVE. Changed data: $(this.form).serialize(),  -> data: $('form').serialize()

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box[]' class="cb" value='1'>
</form>

<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box[]' class="cb" value='2'>
</form>

<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box[]' class="cb" value='3'>
</form>
```

Your jquery script:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cb").click(function(){

        var values = new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='check_box[]']:checked"), function() {
          values.push($(this).val());

        });

        //alert(values);

        $.ajax({url: "urphppage.php", 
        type:'POST',
        data:{ 'cbs':values},
        success: function(result){

             resp = JSON.parse(result);

             alert(resp.sum)

        }

        });
    });
});
```

And your php page :-

```
$msg = array();

$sum=0;



foreach($_POST['cbs'] as $shipping) {

    $sum +=  $shipping;

}

$msg['sum'] = $sum;

echo json_encode($msg);
```